# Ruby & Nokogiri -- Sorting hashed numbers correctly

Tags: ruby

I have a question regarding the sorting of numbers in my hash.
I have stored a hash with items and values, based on a HTML webpage I scraped with Nokogiri.

Now, I managed to sort the hash by the values using the 'sort' method.
However, the numbers show up like this:

1.200
1
10
125
25
3

And I would love to return/sort my values like this:
1
3
10
25
125
1.200

Can someone help me out here? I've tried googling, but my search terms are so general (since I don't know what the correct way of sorting is called), that I couldn't find it.. Any help is welcome!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is `1.200`? Is it supposed to be one thousand two hundreds or one point two float?

Comment: @mudasobwa by the order tho OP mentioned, I believe it is 1200, one thousand two hundreds. Here in Brazil it is the same. In Portuguese we use . (dot) to separate classes and , (comma) to separate decimals, just the opposite of English language.

Comment: You are sorting the numbers as strings and this order is perfect in this case. If you want a numerical order, then convert then with .to_i before storing them in this hash.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read "[ask]" and "[mcve]". Your question is lacking sufficient information to be of use to anyone in the future. Also, there's nothing in the question that applies to Nokogiri or OpenURI.

Comment: Thanks for the welcome and the tips. I'll keep it in mind for my next question!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
▶ %w|1.200 1 10 125 25 3|.map { |e| e.gsub(/\D/, '').to_i }.sort
#⇒ [
#  [0] 1,
#  [2] 3,
#  [2] 10,
#  [3] 25,
#  [4] 125
#  [5] 1200,
# ]
```

Comment: Thanks. Both answers ticked the box for me. I can't believe it was something so simple as to change the format to integer... Saved me some headaches in the future! Thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

As you can see, it's sort by ASCII values, not by number size.

Nokogiri gives you a String, so you have to change the value in your Hash to Integer/Float and then sort it.

Comment: Thanks you too @PandaCool. Your answer combined with mudasobwa's example did the trick for me!